# What is the equivalent method of request.iter_content() in aiohttp?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am writing a small web scraper which gets a big number of images from a specific site. However, the IO speed was slow so I googled and found asyncio and aiohttp to deal with IO bound operation overhead. I combed the aiohttp docs but couldn't find any function that looks like an alternative to iter_content() in requests module. I need it to write the image data to disk. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `ClientResponse.content` attribute. It's a `StreamReader` instance and can be used for reading the response incrementally. From the [docs](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/stable/client.html#streaming-response-content):

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as fd:
    while True:
        chunk = await r.content.read(chunk_size)
        if not chunk:
            break
        fd.write(chunk)
```

`StreamReader` also supports *async* iteration:

```
async for line in r.content:
    ...
async for chunk in r.content.iter_chunked(1024):
    ...
async for slice in r.content.iter_any(): # as much as possible before blocking
    ...
```